# HIbernate reverse engineering configuration eager loading

Tags: reverse-engineering, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-4.x, hibernate-tools, hibernate-onetomany

I can't find any solutions on how to configure Hibernate reverse engineering tools (on Eclipse) for defining properties of domain classes  **fetch = FetchType.EAGER**.

PS:By default all foreign keys defining **fetch = FetchType.LAZY**

For example I define this in reveng.xml and it worked for primary key:

```
<table  name="fin_expence">
    <primary-key>
        <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </primary-key>
</table>
```

I need a solution like this.

```
<foreign-key constraint-name="rel_expence_to_tag">
    <set  lazy="false"></set>
</foreign-key>
```

I have tested this code and it did not work, it threw an error. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hibnerate Reverse Engineer process use Ejb3PropertyGetAnnotation.ftl template to generate Annotations for getters in POJO.
If you see this file,it looks like

```
<#if ejb3>
<#if pojo.hasIdentifierProperty()>
<#if property.equals(clazz.identifierProperty)>
 ${pojo.generateAnnIdGenerator()}
<#-- if this is the id property (getter)-->
<#-- explicitly set the column name for this property-->
</#if>
</#if>

<#if c2h.isOneToOne(property)>
${pojo.generateOneToOneAnnotation(property, cfg)}
<#elseif c2h.isManyToOne(property)>
${pojo.generateManyToOneAnnotation(property)}
<#--TODO support optional and targetEntity-->    
${pojo.generateJoinColumnsAnnotation(property, cfg)}
<#elseif c2h.isCollection(property)>
${pojo.generateCollectionAnnotation(property, cfg)}
<#else>
${pojo.generateBasicAnnotation(property)}
${pojo.generateAnnColumnAnnotation(property)}
</#if>
</#if>
```

Based on the relation type,it is calling a api from actual Pojo class.

Note : there are two types of Pojo class,that is Entity and Component Pojo classes.
In your case you can extended this two classes and write your own implementation for annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by using find and replace task.Below is the beanvalidationtask which will replace lazy to eager for all relations in reverse engineering process.I think this will help to you.

```
public class BeanValidationTask {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(BeanValidationTask.class);

    private final String MANY_TO_ONE_EAGER = "ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER";
    private final String MANY_TO_ONE_LAZY = "ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY";
    private final String ONE_TO_ONE_LAZY_CHILD_REFERENCE = "@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)";
    private final String ONE_TO_ONE_EAGER_CHILD_REFERENCE = "@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn";
    private final String ONE_TO_ONE_LAZY_PARENT_REFERENCE = "@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,";
    private final String ONE_TO_ONE_LAZY_TRANSIENT_PARENT_REFERENCE = "@Transient @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,";
    private final String ONE_TO_MANY = "OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY";
    private final String ONE_TO_MANY_CASCADE = "OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}";
    private final String PRIMARY_KEY_JOIN_COLUMN_IMPORT = "javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;";
    private final String IMPORT = "import ";
    private File searchDirectory;

    public BeanValidationTask(File searchDirectory) {
        this.searchDirectory = searchDirectory;
    }

    /**
     * It changes the below fetch type condition to EAGER.
     *
     * @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY to @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER , cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}
     * @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY to @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER
     */

    private String changeLazyToEagerAndCascade(String content) {
        try {
            content = StringUtils.replace(content, MANY_TO_ONE_LAZY, MANY_TO_ONE_EAGER);
            content = addImportStatement(content,PRIMARY_KEY_JOIN_COLUMN_IMPORT);
            content = StringUtils.replace(content, ONE_TO_ONE_LAZY_CHILD_REFERENCE, ONE_TO_ONE_EAGER_CHILD_REFERENCE);
            content = StringUtils.replace(content, ONE_TO_ONE_LAZY_PARENT_REFERENCE, ONE_TO_ONE_LAZY_TRANSIENT_PARENT_REFERENCE);
            if (!content.contains(ONE_TO_MANY_CASCADE)) {
                content = StringUtils.replace(content, ONE_TO_MANY, ONE_TO_MANY_CASCADE);
            }
            return content;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Change fetch type from LAZY to EAGER failed for relationship 1-1 and 1-M in file {} at path{}. Root cause {}", ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(ex));
            return "";
        }
    }
    private String addImportStatement(String content, final String importStatement) {
        final StringBuffer  importString = new StringBuffer(IMPORT).append(importStatement).append("\n").append(IMPORT);
        content = StringUtils.replaceOnce(content, IMPORT, importString.toString());
        return content;
    }

    public void execute() {
        String[] extensions = new String[]{"java"};
        if (searchDirectory.exists()) {
            Collection<File> filesInDir = FileUtils.listFiles(searchDirectory, extensions, false);
            for (File file : filesInDir)
                try {
                    String content = WMFileUtils.readFileToString(file);
                    content = this.changeLazyToEagerAndCascade(content);
                    WMFileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, content);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Failed to add/update validation into java class file", file.getAbsolutePath(), ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(e));
                }
        }
    }
}
```